# JSON object not being sent through PUT UnityWebRequest

Tags: node.js, json, express, unity-game-engine

So, I have this code in Unity:

```
var www = UnityWebRequest.Put(NetworkManager.Instance.data.ConnectionURL + "/upload-schedule", contents);
www.SetRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
yield return www.SendWebRequest();
 
if (www.result == UnityWebRequest.Result.ConnectionError)
{
    Debug.LogError("There was an error uploading the schedule");
}
 
else {
    string downloadContents = www.downloadHandler.text;
    Debug.Log(downloadContents);
}
```

And then I have this node express application receiving this data:

```
app.put('/upload-schedule', (req, res) => {
    var filePath = "./data/schedule.json";
    var data = JSON.stringify(req.body);
 
    // Write file
    fs.writeFile(filePath, data, (err) => {
 
        // Dip if an error is found
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
         
        // Send found data
        res.send("Successfuly uploaded file!");
        console.log("Successfuly uploaded file!");
    });
});
```

For some reason, this works fine on localhost, but, as soon as I use my web api, req.body always comes out empty. Does anyone know the reason for this and how I can fix it? Thank you

Comment: Could you post a complete reproducible example? What is `contents`?

Comment: Just a JSON object, I didn't find anything wrong with it, but you can check it out here: https://pastebin.com/9WNVgjUj